# Gaussian integrals with gamma matrices in their exponents

Tags: field-theory, integration, dirac-matrices, trace

I should evaluate Gaussian integrals in the 1+1 Minkowski space, which read

$$
I_{1}= \int d^{2}k  \, {\rm Tr}\big[ \gamma^{5} \gamma^{\eta} \gamma^{\kappa} e^{\alpha k^{\mu}k_{\mu} + \beta \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}  M^{* \sigma}_{\mu} M^{\iota}_{\nu} k_{\sigma} k_{\iota}} \big],\\
I_{2}= \int d^{2}k  \, {\rm Tr}\big[ \gamma^{5} e^{\alpha k^{\mu}k_{\mu} + \beta \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} M^{* \kappa}_{\mu} M^{\iota}_{\nu} k_{\kappa} k_{\iota}} \big],\\
I_{3}= \int d^{2}k  \, {\rm Tr}\big[ \gamma^{5} e^{\alpha k^{\mu}k_{\mu} + \beta \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{5} M^{* \kappa}_{\mu} M^{\iota}_{\nu} k_{\kappa} k_{\iota}} \big],
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants and the diagonal matrix $M$ has nonzero complex elements~($M_{\mu}^{\mu}=v_{\mu}$). Using the Euclidean convention $g^{\mu \nu} =- \delta^{\mu \nu}$ at $\beta=0$ results in
$$
I_{1}= \int d^{2}k  \, {\rm Tr}\big[ \gamma^{5} \gamma^{\eta} \gamma^{\kappa} e^{-\alpha k_{\mu}k_{\mu} } \big] =-2 \frac{\pi}{\alpha} \varepsilon^{\eta \kappa} , \\
I_{2}=0,\\
I_{3}=0,
$$
where I have used ${\rm Tr}[\gamma^{5}]=0$, and ${\rm Tr}[\gamma^{5} \gamma^{\eta} \gamma^{\kappa}] = -2 \varepsilon^{\eta \kappa}$.
How can I calculate $I_{1}$, $I_{2}$, and $I_{3}$ with nonzero $\beta$?

EDIT: A simplified question is how the following integral should be calculated
$$
I_{0}= \int d^{2}k  \, e^{ \gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}  M^{* \sigma}_{\mu} M^{\iota}_{\nu} k_{\sigma} k_{\iota}} .
$$

Comment: There's a problem of indices in your exponent, $\mu$ and $\nu$ appear three times in a product.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Corrected!

Comment: Have you tried calculating $\int dxe^{-Ax^2}$ where $A$ is some matrix? If you can find what properties $A$ must have, the generalization should be about as straightforward as the usual generalization from the 1d Gaussian integral to more complicated versions. I think it should be pretty lax...might need some weak form of invertibility like a pseudoinverse.

Comment: In this way, the matrix $A$ comprises $MM^{*}$ and $\gamma$ matrices. This Gaussian integral after the integration then generates a factor with the determinate of A in the denominator. This seems very weird to me. I think I should treat gamma matrices differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand out the exponential using identites such a $(v^\mu \gamma_\mu)^2 = |v|^2{\mathbb I}$. It may well help introduce a new variable $\omega$ and us  a Hubbard Stratanovich transform to replace
$
(v^\mu \gamma_\mu)(v^{*\nu} \gamma_\nu) 
$
by something like
$i\omega (v^\mu \gamma_\mu) + \frac 12 \omega^2
$ (signs not checked) befoe expanding.